# Principal bundle associated to a fiber bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $\pi : E\to B$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ over a finite complex $B$ whose structure group is a compact Lie group $G$. How can we determine the principal $G$-bundle associated to $\pi$? For example if we consider the bundle $S({\gamma}_{1}\times {\gamma}_{1})\to {BO}_{1}\times {BO}_{1}$ where ${\gamma}_{1}\to {BO}_{1}$ is the $1$-dimensional  universal vector bundle over ${BO}_{1}$ and $S({\gamma}_{1}\times {\gamma}_{1})$ is the sphere bundle of ${\gamma}_{1}\times {\gamma}_{1}$ over ${BO}_{1}\times {BO}_{1}$, then what is the principal ${O}_{1}\times {O}_{1}$-bundle associated to $S({\gamma}_{1}\times {\gamma}_{1})\to {BO}_{1}\times {BO}_{1}$?

Comment: Concerning your last question, the principal bundle is just $EO(1)\times EO(1)$. The principal bundle comes first; you don't need to go through the vector or sphere bundles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The associated principal bundle is the set of pairs $(b,i)$ so that $i$ is an isomorphism of $E_b$ with $F$ as $G$-space.